# Avoid string copy in the case of returning input string

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following function

```
std::string DoSomething(int x, std::string_view data) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return std::string(data);
  }
  return SomeOtherCalculation(data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string a = "aaa";
  std::string b = DoSomething(0, a);
  std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

When x = 0 it'd be wasteful to copy 'data' into a new string (because the caller already has 'data' string available).

Is there any modification to the signature of 'DoSomething' to avoid a string copy when x = 0?

Update: since some people have asked, 'x' is not a constant, and I don't want to move the 'if (x == 0)' logic to the caller because there are multiple callers of DoSomething, so leaving 'if (x == 0)' at caller sight would mean that I have to repeat it multiple times at the caller (and introduce chance of forgetting to have 'if (x == 0)' for a new caller.

Comment: I'd rely on RVO

Comment: you could just not copy the string `if (x == 0) return {};`

Comment: Is the value of your `int x` always known at compile time?

Comment: Will the `x` argument always be passed as a compile-time constant value? Then perhaps some template and `constexpr` tricks could be used to avoid the copying. Otherwise it's not really possible as there's really no way to know at runtime that the view is of the same string that will be assigned to by the caller.

Comment: And if the caller knows this case, why assign the result back to the same variable used in the argument list in the first place? Why not plain `DoSomething(0, a);` without the assignment? An optimizing compiler might be able to inline the function call and just skip the copying of the string.

Comment: x may or may not be a constant. The main function is just to demonstrate a possible use.

Also I don't want to do this if (x == 0) logic in the caller because there are multiple callers of this function. Doing so would just scatter the logic at the callers and cause potential bug when a caller forgets to have the if statement.

Comment: Then you don't really have a choice. And this smells very much like premature optimization anyway. Have you actually tried to measure or benchmark or profile it (on an optimized build)? Is it a top-two or three bottleneck in your program? Unless it becomes that, then my suggestion is to not bother with it. Spending hours, perhaps even days, on something that might not matter in the long run is, quite honestly, a waste of time.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You'd still be constructing a `std::string`

Comment: @vda8888 "*When `x = 0` it'd be wasteful to copy `data` into a new string (because the caller already has `data` string available)*" - `DoSomething()` doesn't know that, though. Only the caller knows that. All `DoSomething()` knows is the `std::string_view` it is given, which **may or may not** be backed by a `std::string`  (that is the whole point of `std::string_view` - to expose string-like behaviors for things that are not strings to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you could just take a raw reference to a string instead of a non owning view:

```cpp
void DoSomething(int x, std::string& data) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return;
  }
  data = SomeOtherCalculation(data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string a = "aaa";
  DoSomething(0, a);
  std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

In general, these sort of in-out style parameters are not a very intuitive API.
But if you measured that this is a significant bottleneck in your application, and the compiler cannot optimize it for some reason,
this is sometimes justified